# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook with dlls?

Tags: dll, outlook

I have a problem with the dlls I guess.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

                // Get the MAPI namespace.
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

                // Log on by using the default profile or existing session (no dialog box).
                oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true);

                // Alternate logon method that uses a specific profile name.
                // TODO: If you use this logon method, specify the correct profile name
                // and comment the previous Logon line.
                //oNS.Logon("profilename",Missing.Value,false,true);

                //Get the Inbox folder.
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oInbox = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

                //Get the Items collection in the Inbox folder.
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items oItems = oInbox.Items;


                // Get the first message.
                // Because the Items folder may contain different item types,
                // use explicit typecasting with the assignment.
               // Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oItems.GetFirst();
               // Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oItems;
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail in oItems) 
{Activity.StartTime = mail.ReceivedTime;
                              Activity.EndTime = mail.ReceivedTime;
                                Activity.Details = mail.Subject;
                               Activity.Notes = mail.Body;}
```

I am able to access mail.Body , Subject etc but I can not access mail.Sender and mail.SenderEmailAddress 
Does anybody had this problem? 
I see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn320330.aspx
that it is a mailItem property so I do not know what is going on with my .dll. I have added as Reference C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Office\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Office.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll
Do I need to add more .dlls to get access to sender property?

Comment: "I can not access mail.Sender and mail.SenderEmailAddress " - what exactly do you mean? Do you get an error? What is it?

Comment: when I try to use one of the two I get "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem does not contain a definition for SenderEmailAddress"

Comment: What do you see if you go to the MailItem definition?